# Node.js: Using passport, is it possible to customize the temporary value saved by the serialize function?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

We know that the passport will keep the authenticate result in the req.user by using

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) { cb(null,user); })
```

I'm trying to return the result and the status code from the server. In order to get both of them, I'm trying to find a way to save those two in different vessel. For example down below.

```
passport.serializer____(function(statuscode, user, cb) { cb(null, user, statuscode); } )
```

In the customized serializer above, it saved the result in req.user and the statuscode in req.___ (save status code). However, the way I used now is to saved them both in req.user.

Comment: Why don't you just store the statuscode separately?

Comment: @GlenPierce Thanks for reply. My goal is to save it separately.  As I mention above, I have issue with getting them from the serializer, serializeUser only saved them in req.user.